# Change Color of Daterange line in Jetpack Compose DatePicker

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I used the DatePicker in Jetpack Compose.

```
Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
                    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(initialSelectedDateMillis = 1578096000000)
                    DatePicker(state = datePickerState, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors(titleContentColor = Color.Green,headlineContentColor = Color.Red,))}
```

I could modify colors with `color = DatePickerDefaults.colors()` but i did not manage to modify the line with the selected year and month and the arrows to navigate(circled red in the picture). How can I change the color of the elements in this line?

I used `color = DatePickerDefaults.colors()` as a property for the DatePicker. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the colors of that line separately by providing specific colors;

The reason is if you check the source code of the DatePicker from material3 implementation, after some digging, the composable you are searching for is called `MonthsNavigation`; here is its signature:

[image]

You can find it in the file `DatePicker.kt` under the package name `androidx.compose.material3`, which is a simple row with some icon buttons and a year picker.

And as you can see, you can't customize anything here by passing parameters such as color, so I think it takes the default colors from your theme colors, consider playing with the colors there!

Or you can copy the code of the `DatePicker.kt` file, so you create your own custom date picker, and set the colors yourself!